# Quick sort explanation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I was studying Quick sort, I found the algorithm explained [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cmoreno/ece250/quick-sort-complete-example.pdf)

best to my understanding, but I have a question at one of the step.

Could someone explained me properly what would be the steps till the pivot **57** is kept to its right placed, if the number **76** in this point as shown in the image was **7** ?

[image]

I think it would be more helpful if the reader first see the steps explained in the slides as I found out there are many other different approach for explaining quick sort algorithm.

**Editted:**
I guessed the final sequenced would be like

24  49  16  38  55  21  36  9  *7  *57  81  85  63  79  74  85  97  61  77  70  *68. (as mentioned by nullpointer)

Did the flow stopped as the blue finds 68 as the greatest element on the right side and **skipped checking lesser element** as the index of blue crossed/ met the red index?

Comment: you'd skip over 7 with blue, and halt at 7 with red, being done one element to the right than with `76`

Comment: The purpose of a partition step is to establish that all small elements are placed on the left of the large elements. Small/large classification is decided by comparison with a "pivot" value. For the algorithm to progress, one must ensure that there is at least one small and one large element.

Comment: @YvesDaoust as you mentioned, there should be one small **AND** one large (requires two numbers), what would be the flow in the above case since there is only one element left to be compared.

Comment: When there is a single element left, partitioning is pointless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you please tell me the answer to the last question according to the flow explained in the slides? What I am concerned is **skipped checking lesser element** part?

Answer (score 3):

Contd..[* blue pointer ; ** red pointer ; *** vacant]
Pivot =57

```
=> 24  49  16  38  55  21  36  *68  7  **9  81  85  63  79  74  85  97  61  77  70  ***

=> 24  49  16  38  55  21  36  *9  7  **68  81  85  63  79  74  85  97  61  77  70  ***
```

I expect things until this would be clear as they are as it is. 9 and 68 are swapped. Now the next number smaller than 57 from right end is 7(so **) and number larger than it form left is 68(so *).

```
 => 24  49  16  38  55  21  36  9  **7  *68  81  85  63  79  74  85  97  61  77  70  ***
```

But since the indexes would not satisfy the conditions further, hence the number with red pointer 68 would be moved to the vacant space and 57 to its position in the middle. Hence the sequence should be :

```
=> 24  49  16  38  55  21  36  9  **7  *57  81  85  63  79  74  85  97  61  77  70  ***68
```

Comment: Could you please explained me like the way it was explained in the slides. I guessed the sequence would be like that, but how?

Comment: @Tootsie_Roll edited the answer...no diagrams though but tried to provide a better visual

Comment: In your flow, you try to find the smaller element first. Does priority of  finding either the smaller element first or larger element first matters?

Comment: no it doesn't, both of them are searched in the same step

Comment: My important doubt is, at the point as mentioned in my question xxxx till 9 on the left side and 68 till xxxx blank has been sorted as per pivot. And the  only place remaining to be compared is the position of 7, so according to you, you need to find the largest element on the right side even in the already sorted area (ie at 68)?

Comment: `The indices are out of order, so we stop` quoting from your source itself.

Comment: @OnePunchMan does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

A variation of quicksort:

```
void swap(int *i, int *j)
{
    int t = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = t;
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = (lo + hi)/2, k = hi;
    int pivot;
    if (a[k] < a[i])            // median of 3
        swap(a+k, a+i);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        swap(a+j, a+i);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        swap(a+k, a+j);
    pivot = a[j];
    showa(lo, hi);
    while (i <= k) {            // partition
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[k] > pivot)
            k--;
        if (i <= k) {
            swap(a+i, a+k);
            i++;
            k--;
            showa(lo, hi);
        }
    }
    if (lo < k)                 // recurse
        QuickSort(a, lo, k);
    if (i < hi)
        QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```

The output, with '*' after a swapped number:

```
57 70 97 38 63 21 85 68 76  9 81 36 55 79 74 85 16 61 77 49 24 
24*70 97 38 63 21 85 68 76  9 57*36 55 79 74 85 16 61 77 49 81*
24 49*97 38 63 21 85 68 76  9 57 36 55 79 74 85 16 61 77 70*81 
24 49 16*38 63 21 85 68 76  9 57 36 55 79 74 85 97*61 77 70 81 
24 49 16 38 55*21 85 68 76  9 57 36 63*79 74 85 97 61 77 70 81 
24 49 16 38 55 21 36*68 76  9 57 85*63 79 74 85 97 61 77 70 81 
24 49 16 38 55 21 36 57*76  9 68*85 63 79 74 85 97 61 77 70 81 
24 49 16 38 55 21 36 57  9*76*68 85 63 79 74 85 97 61 77 70 81 
 9*49 16 38 24*21 36 57 55*                                    
 9 21*16 38 24 49*36 57 55                                     
 9 21 16 24*38*49 36 57 55                                     
 9 21 16 24                                                    
 9 16*21*24                                                    
 9 16                                                          
 9 16                                                          
      21 24                                                    
      21 24                                                    
            36*49 38*57 55                                     
            36 38*49*57 55                                     
            36 38                                              
            36 38                                              
                  49 55*57*                                    
                  49 55 57                                     
                           74*68 85 63 79 76*85 97 61 77 70 81 
                           74 68 70*63 79 76 85 97 61 77 85*81 
                           74 68 70 63 61*76 85 97 79*77 85 81 
                           74 68 70 63 61 76 85 97 79 77 85 81 
                           61*68 70 63 74*                     
                           61 68 63*70*74                      
                           61 63*68*                           
                           61 63 68                            
                                    70 74                      
                                    70 74                      
                                             79*97 81*77 85 85*
                                             79 77*81 97*85 85 
                                             79 77 81 97 85 85 
                                             77*79*            
                                             77 79             
                                                      85*85 97*
                                                      85 85 97 
                                                         85 97 
                                                         85 97 
 9 16 21 24 36 38 49 55 57 61 63 68 70 74 76 77 79 81 85 85 97
```